# adding multiple options in magento

Tags: magento, store

I'm making a site for a t-shirt screen printer. They offer 10 different styles of shirts, about 8 colors per shirt, and 5 sizes. All of the prices vary depending on style and size.

What I need to do is show the main product which is the screen print design, and then they must pick all the shirt options. How do I configure the menu so when they select say "shirt style X" that it gives them the custom options and prices for the style.

I basically want to just add these options to each screen print design as addon prices and options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Magento's configurable products to accomplish this.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product/